# Using Alias with MySql

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to add an amount to the rows returned from a select.  I've been trying things along the lines of:

```
select *,
       3 as amount
  from products
 where etc....
```

...and it works.  However, I want to do the same thing for lots of rows in one go along the lines of:

```
select *,
       3 as amount,
       2 as amount,
       4 as amount
  from products 
 where id in ('1','2','3')
```

However this keeps adding amount columns and not changing the values in each row returned.

The amount is really an amount the users wants, it could be 1-99-4-2 or any number. I wanted to get a table with the results like: products amount --------------------------- ... 1 ... 99 ... 4 ... 2 I just wanted all the mount in one column thats why I was using select ? as amount select ? as amount but it just doesn't seem to work that way :-)

Comment: Can you please tell how you expect result look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  id, ELT(id, 3, 2, 4) AS amount
FROM    products 
WHERE   id IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each alias a unique name. For example, amount1, amount2, etc.

EDIT> If you'd like sum of the columns, use SELECT SUM(amount1, amount2, amount3, ...) FROM ...

Comment: That looks like what I need. Thanks.  Is there a way to get the amount in to one column after?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT *, 3 AS amt1, 2 AS amt2, 4 AS amt3 FROM products WHERE id IN ('1','2','3')
```

Comment: That looks like what I need. Thanks.  Is there a way to get the amount in to one column after?

Thanks for posting the code as well, I'm new to this and it really helps.